# ADT (using a header file, source file and main file) in C

Tags: c, header, adt

I am trying to create a simple ADT using a structure that takes 2 dates. Then returns an age. It must use a Header file, a source file for the Header file, and a main file.

This is what I have it runs and nothing happens. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

age.h

```
#ifndef AGE_H_

#define AGE_H_

typedef struct getage * Age;

#define MAX  5

Age get_Age(int birthYear, int yearNow);

void age_Destroy(Age a);


#endif
```

age.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "age.h"


struct getage {

       int birthYear;

       int yearNow;

};

Age a[1];

Age get_Age(int birthYear, int yearNow){

             int giveAge = 0;

             giveAge = a[0]->yearNow - a[0]->birthYear;

             printf("%d",giveAge);

             return 0;

            }

void age_Destroy(Age a){

                     free(a);

     }
```

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include "age.h"


void age_print(Age a);

void age_print(Age a){

        printf("%d\n", &a);

}



int main() {

    Age a;

    get_Age(1986, 2020);
    
    age_print(a);

    printf("%d\n", &a);

    system("pause");

    //age_Destroy(a);
    
    
}
```

Comment: One of your wrong points is `printf("%d\n", &a);`. This is passing `Age*` to `%d`, which requires `int`, and invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — TL;DR usually not, but function pointers might be an exception.

Comment: Your code never assigns any values to an instance of your struct. You define get_Age to return a pointer to your struct but you return an int. You never allocate an instance to the variable a. It is simply a pointer to a struct, not an instance of a struct.

Comment: @JimRogers — it returns a null pointer, not an `int`.  `0` is a legitimate representation for a null pointer.

Comment: @JimRogers Actually there are no instance of the struct allocated. Values are read from `NULL` in the function `get_Age`.

Comment: What should the function `age_print` do? Note that the function cannot access the members of the structure because the declaration of structure is not provided for `main.c` (inside the header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are wrong:

- In the function `get_Age`:

  - Instead of allocating structures, `a[0]` (global variable, initialized to `NULL`) is dereferenced.
  - `0` (converted to `NULL`) is returned instead of returning an age.
- In the function `age_Destroy`:

  - `free()` is used without declaration nor including proper header.
- In the function `age_print`:

  - Data having wrong type is passed to `printf()`: `%d` requests `int` but `Age*` is passed.
- In the function `main`:

  - The return value of `get_Age` is dropped.
  - Data having wrong type is passed to `printf()`: `%d` requests `int` but `Age*` is passed.

Fixed code that won't cause Segmentation Fault nor undefined behavior:

age.h (not changed)

```
#ifndef AGE_H_

#define AGE_H_

typedef struct getage * Age;

#define MAX  5

Age get_Age(int birthYear, int yearNow);

void age_Destroy(Age a);

#endif
```

age.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc() and free()

#include "age.h"


struct getage {

       int birthYear;

       int yearNow;

};

Age get_Age(int birthYear, int yearNow){

        Age a = malloc(sizeof(*a)); // allocate a structure

        if (a == NULL) { perror("malloc"); exit(1); }

        a->yearNow = yearNow; // assign data

        a->birthYear = birthYear;

        int giveAge = 0;

        giveAge = a->yearNow - a->birthYear;

        printf("%d",giveAge);

        return a; // return pointer to the allocated structure

}

void age_Destroy(Age a){

        free(a);

}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h> // more portable header for system()

#include <stdio.h>

#include "age.h"


void age_print(Age a);

void age_print(Age a){

        printf("%p\n", (void*)a); // use valid combination of format and data

}



int main() {

    Age a;

    a = get_Age(1986, 2020); // assign the return value
    
    age_print(a);

    printf("%p\n", (void*)a); // use valid combination of format and data

    system("pause");

    age_Destroy(a); // enable freeing
    
    
}
```

(Some behavior may look weird, but I believe this is valid because not desired behavior is described.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Got exactly want i wanted after a few tweaks of the solution you gave. Thanks again.